# Community detection using Netwokit with PLP and PLM ( Python 3.x )

Tags: python, python-3.x, cluster-computing, python-3.6, networkit

I'm not able to find a good documentation to use PLP and PLM algoritms. I need to detect community in a graph using networkit's libraries.
I've found only this link: https://networkit.iti.kit.edu/api/community.html but I don't understand what kind of function can give me the community's structure and how I can run the algorithm.
I need some explaination like this:  https://networkit.iti.kit.edu/api/doxyhtml/class_networ_kit_1_1_p_l_p.html#abeb42305639e48a3160a45aee354783a (C++) where is clear that I can run the algorithm and then use toString() to see the structure. 
I need a Graph G, I think, but I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 2):

As many classes in NetworKit, both `PLP` and `PLM` include a `run()` method that executes the algorithm and you need to invoke it before getting the result.
Also, there is no need to use the `toString()` method to get the community structure;
you can use the `getPartition()` method (included in both `PLP` and `PLM`, see the [documentation](https://networkit.iti.kit.edu/api/community.html?highlight=communitydetector#networkit.community.CommunityDetector)) which returns a `Partition` object that represents the community structure (you can find the documentation of `Partition` [here](https://networkit.iti.kit.edu/api/community.html?#networkit.community.Partition)).

See below for a simple example:

```
from networkit import *

# In this example I generate a graph with a random community structure.
# In your code use your own graph.
g = generators.ClusteredRandomGraphGenerator(100, 10, 0.5, 0.01).generate()

# Creating an instance of PLP and running the algorithm.
# Use community.PLM(g) to run the PLM algorithm.
plp = community.PLP(g).run()

# Getting the Partition object.
plpPartition = plp.getPartition()

# Getting the community IDs.
plpCommunityIDs = plpPartition.getSubsetIds()

# Getting the community ID of each node of the graph g.
plpCommunities = plpPartition.getVector()
```

Each community is associated with a unique integer id, and each node is associated to a community id. `plpCommunityIDs` is a set that contains all the community ids, while `plpCommunities` is a vector of size *n* (number of nodes of the graph) that contains the community id of each node (for example, use `c = plpCommunities[v]` to store in `c` the community id of node `v`).